# Check of non-overlapping elements postgres

Tags: postgresql

Postgres documentation seems to only show how to check if two arrays have overlapping elements.
I need to know if the two array have non-overlapping elements.

So if I have 2 arrays:

```
array_1 = '{1, 2, 3, 4}'
array_2 = '{0, 3, 4, 5}'
```

This should return false. Checking for not equal doesn't work because they may not be equal in that one array might have the same integer repeat several times.

Is this comparison possible?

Comment: your problem is unclear.. do you mean "two array have non-overlapping elements" IS "one array has element that is not in second array?"

Answer (score 0):

Two sets are non-overlapping if there are no elements in common, so using the [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) operator for arrays and negating the result give you what you want.

```sql
# select NOT (ARRAY[1,2,3,4] && ARRAY[0,3,3,3,3,4,5]) AS non_overlapping;
 non_overlapping 
-----------------
 f
(1 row)

# select NOT (ARRAY[1,2,8,9] && ARRAY[0,3,3,3,3,4,5]) AS non_overlapping;
 non_overlapping 
-----------------
 t
(1 row)
```